# How to see what users are doing in Windows Server 2008

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, administrator, administration

If you are the Administrator and users are remotely logged into your system, is there a way for you to see what those users see?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for [Configure Remote Control of Remote Desktop Services Sessions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771538.aspx) :

> You can monitor the actions of a
>   client logged on to an RD Session Host
>   server by using remote control from
>   another session. Remote control allows
>   you to either observe or actively
>   control a client session. If you
>   choose to actively control a client
>   session, you will be able to input
>   keyboard and mouse actions to the
>   session. You can warn a client that
>   you want to remotely control their
>   session by choosing to display a
>   message on the client that asks
>   permission to view or take part in the
>   session.

The article applies to Windows Server 2008 R2, but I have seen a similar mechanism already used since Windows Server 2003 R2.

Answer (score 1):

In Computer Management | Shared Folders you should be able to see the users logged in and what files they are currently accessing (select Shares, Sessions and Open Files)